# symfony3 - how to choose a object type in createform?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

here is a very standard code to handle a form

```
$account = new Account();
$form = $this->createForm('TEST\RegistrationBundle\Form\AccountType', $account);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if($form->isValid())
{
     $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($account);
     $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

     return $this->redirectToRoute('test_registration_homepage');
}

return $this->render('TESTRegistrationBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('form_account' => $form->createView()));
```

I also did some inheritance on `TEST\RegistrationBundle\Form\AccountType` with 2 other type called `AccountHSType` and `AccountHGType` which only add a new field `attributHS` or `attributHG`.

What I would like to do is to have the correct type in `createFrom()` depending on the submiter parameters, so have :

```
$form = $this->createForm('TEST\RegistrationBundle\Form\AccountHSType', $account);
```

or

```
$form = $this->createForm('TEST\RegistrationBundle\Form\AccountHGType', $account);
```

or

```
$form = $this->createForm('TEST\RegistrationBundle\Form\AccountType', $account);
```

The desired type is selected by the user and submit with the form along with other attributes. A simple way to select the correct type is to use :

```
$type_id = $request->query->get('city_id');
```

However I was wondering if there is a smarter way to do so, for example to hydrate the object `$Account` earlier.

Hope I am clear enough.

Thanks in advance

D

Comment: If type of form is selected by the user along with the form itself, then how do you know which form to render in first place?

Comment: In the first place I used `$type_id = $request->query->get('city_id');` and then I hydrate a object `$Account`. I can do the same but as the form is submitted I was wondering if there could be a way to hydrate the object earlier than `$form->handlerRequest($request)`

Comment: I didn't ask what have you tried. You've already described that in your question. I asked where the basic information comes from. Let's skip the whole form handling for now. First step is to render it. How to you know if it should be `AccountHSType` or `AccountHGType`?